# Incorrect Graphics Showing, 16.04 on Poweredge 1950 III

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I'm currently trying to get a Dell Poweredge 1950 III to run Ubuntu 16.04. The install went fine, however the GUI is barely usable. Going to Settings>Details shows this as the graphics device

```
llvmpipe (llvm 5.0, 128 bits)
```

Google returns basically nothing about this, but it appears to be a driver. However, running

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

returns it is an ATI ES1000, using a raedon driver. It only has 64k memory, but as far as I can tell it still meets the minimum system requirements for 16.04.

Is this the correct driver for this graphics chip?

I haven't had a chance to get this connected to a network yet, hopefully tomorrow I'll be able to make an ethernet cable long enough to reach it. If any system updates fix this, I'll report back here.

EDIT: I forgot to add the additional drivers page shows nothing, but that may be because it's not connected to any network.

Comment: i have a couple of poweredge 1950s (rack mount servers) but they are not designed for graphics. I'd suggest Ubuntu Server, or a lighter DEsktop than Unity for them if you really need a gui.  Radeon sounds right.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could get away with unity. Graphics requirements for a GUI aren't well established with Ubuntu.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  lists "* 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB" as requirements; I haven't looked at mine but specs (http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/pe_1950_III_spec_sheet.pdf) [min 16mb] don't meet that minimum (*for unity or gnome; gnome didn't cause it to change*) .

Comment: Well shoot, I looked right over that apparently. Thanks. I guess I'm stuck with CLI only for now.